# Overo Waterstorm RTC power usage

Tags: rtc, gumstix

I am trying to work out the current draw from Vbackup when the RTC is kept alive but the rest of the system is shutdown. I am trying to determine the size of the backup cell that I need for my application.

I am working with the GUM3703 device

Comment: You need to provide links to the manufacturer's datasheet for the GUM3703 and for the RTC device.

Answer (score 0):

On the Overo Waterstorm (GUM3703W), "VBACKUP" is connected to pin M14 on the TPS65950 (http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps65950.pdf). Table 5-22 provides the typical power consumption for the use case where no main power source is connected: [image]

Note that 3.2V is used as the typical backup battery supply voltage for this calculation (see page 19 of the datasheet):
[image]

Hope this helps!